# Random large coloured emojis appearing in Thunderbird email list

Tags: 18.04, thunderbird, emoji

Since I upgraded from Ubuntu 17.10 to Ubuntu 18.04 whenever I open Thunderbird there is a globe icon, and sometimes also  headphones icon, appearing in my list of new emails.

[image]

These icons hide the titles of my emails. When I move the mouse over the icons they partially disappear. When I scroll down there is another globe icon further down the list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Installing the `fonts-symbola` package fixes the problem.

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-symbola
```

Comment: This indeed fixed the problem. But what is the reason behind it ? :D